# laravel routing problem syntax error, unexpected 'opis' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Tags: php, laravel

needs to generate a sitelink via routing. 
until now I wrote:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="{{ route('farmyw', app()->getLocale()) }}">{{ __('flipmenu.button') }}</a>
```

and everything worked fine until I need to give the routing name from the translation.
I'm using the code:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="{{ route('{{$flip->getTranslatedAttribute('button')}}', app()->getLocale()) }}">{{ __('flipmenu.button') }}</a>
```

all give the following error I will be grateful for every hint

```
<?php $__currentLoopData = $flips; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $flip): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
    <div class="flip" farmy pv>
        <div class="front" style="background-image: url(<?php echo e(Voyager::image( $flip->image )); ?>)">
            <h1 class="text-shadow front-shadow"><?php echo $flip->getTranslatedAttribute('name'); ?></hi>
        </div>
        <div class="back" style="background-color:#304c84;">
            <h2><?php echo $flip->getTranslatedAttribute('nameback'); ?></h2>
            <p style="text-align: justify; color: white;"><?php echo $flip->getTranslatedAttribute('opis'); ?></p>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="<?php echo e(route('{{$flip->getTranslatedAttribute('opis')); ?>', app()->getLocale()) }}"><?php echo e(__('flipmenu.button')); ?></a>
            "><?php echo $flip->getTranslatedAttribute('name'); ?></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>


<?php echo e($flip->button); ?>
```

Many thanks for help

MY web route file bellow

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{locale}', 
    'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'],
    'middleware' => 'setlocale'
  ], function() {

Route::get('/', 'FlipController@index')->name('menu');
Route::get('/', 'FooterController@index')->name('footer');


Route::get('/', 'MainController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/farmy', 'PfarmController@index')->name('farmy');
Route::get('/farmyw', 'FarmywController@index')->name('farmyw');
Route::get('/kariera', 'KarieraController@index')->name('kariera');
Route::get('/kontakt', 'KontaktController@index')->name('kontakt');
Route::get('/oferta', 'OfertaController@index')->name('oferta');
Route::get('/onas', 'MainController@index')->name('onas');
Route::get('/pobranie', 'PobranieController@index')->name('pobranie');
Route::get('/rada', 'RadaController@index')->name('rada');
Route::get('/relacje', 'RelacjeController@index')->name('relacje');
Route::get('/stacja', 'StacjaController@index')->name('stacja');
Route::get('/stacje', 'StationController@index')->name('stacje');
Route::get('/wspieramy', 'WspieramyController@index')->name('wspieramy');
Route::get('/zarzad', 'ZarzadController@index')->name('zarzad');
Route::get('/certyfikaty', 'CertyfikatyController@index')->name('certyfikaty');
Route::get('/galeria', 'GaleriaController@index')->name('galeria');

});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});
```

Comment: please put your route.php file.

Comment: also avoid using non-English words in the code. At least if you decide to post it on SO

Comment: `{{ route('{{...` - not sure if embedding multiple `{{` is allowed. Try removing the 2nd instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code is wrong:

```
<?php echo e(route('{{$flip->getTranslatedAttribute('opis')); ?>
```

You're already in PHP context, not blade, so the braces ({{}}) are not necessary. If you were using an IDE like PHPStorm, it'd have pointed that error out.

It should be (PHP context):

```
 <?php echo e(route($flip->getTranslatedAttribute('opis'))); ?>
```

or (blade context):

```
    {!! e(route($flip->getTranslatedAttribute('opis'))) !!}
```

Comment: im using blade files.
<a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="{{ route('farmyw', app()->getLocale()) }}">{!! $flip->getTranslatedAttribute('name') !!}</a>
that a link code and i need to put route name from other table

Comment: I know you're using blade files, but using <?php ?> takes you to PHP context and PHP doesn't recognise the use {{ }}, only blade does, hence the error you're seeing. If you replace the line, the error will be gone.

Comment: Link like this one works fine  href="{{ route('farmyw', app()->getLocale()) }}" 
the problem is that I have to enter the routing name from the table using {!! $ flip-> getTranslatedAttribute ('name') !!} of this command and I don't necessarily know how to combine it

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. But this should work: `<a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="{{ route($flip->getTranslatedAttribute('button'), app()->getLocale()) }}">{{ __('flipmenu.button') }}</a>`

Comment: works;) thanks for the information. I missed one bracket. The most accurate hint.